# Android ORMLite DatabaseConfigUtil

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite on our Android app, and I've previously set up an `ormlite_config.txt` as described in the documentation

http://ormlite.com/docs/table-config

I've now updated my classes, so I need to regenerate the file, but I can no longer get my DatabaseConfigUtil to run in Eclipse. I've set the Run Configuration as described in the documentation, choosing the local JRE and removing the Android bootstrap entry from the Classpath tab. But I just get a whole bunch of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for all the Android-derived classes in my project.

I've obviously changed something since I originally generated the `ormlite_config.txt` file, as I didn't have any problems before, but I can't see what I've done to break everything.

Can somebody tell me exactly what I should have in my Classpath / source tabs?

Comment: Having gone back to the last version of the code where I successfully generated ormlite_config.txt, and then used git bisect to track down where it stopped working, it turns out that the cause of the problem was the upgrade from ormlite-android-4.42.jar to ormlite-android-4.43.jar. The OrmLiteConfigUtil class was updated, in particular the findAnnotatedClasses method. It looks like this isn't working for me.

Comment: Look here also. This is how to set it up on Android Studio http://stackoverflow.com/a/31946807/976550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the instructions in the documentation were all that was required, there was just a pair of bugs introduced in 4.43 that prevented it working as it should. These have now been fixed, and will presumably be in the next version. See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ormlite-android/nBuQTVpCs0g

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem and found out a solution myself.

I think the problem came from Google's ADT plugin. Since the plugin manages the Android libraries as private libraries, ORMLite Util cannot find the Android related classes in the project's build path.

The solution is to manually add the *android.jar* from your android sdk folder (in my case it's C:\android-sdk\platforms\android-18) into the build path as an external jar.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the Android Lib from Bootrap Entries!

Do as follows:

- Project > Properties > Run/Debug Settings
- Select the class you want to compile and click edit
- open tab "classpath" and remove Android Lib from Bootstrap Entries